# How to complete remove Livepatch from Ubuntu 20.04.3?

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

How can i permanently and completely  remove Livepatch from Ubuntu?

I tried these steps but Livepatch was still present and i could run it!

First of all i run the following command:

`sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch`

Then i run:

`sudo rm /etc/machine-id`

after that i reboot my system.
i checked if canonical-livepatch was removed by running:

`snap list`

canonical-livepatch was removed but it was still available in settings and the icon was also present and i can still run it!

Comment: @Someone  Livepatch is useful for Ubuntu server where you cant restart the entire server. Im using Ubuntu Desktop and i dont use it and im also removing everyhting that im not using.

Comment: So do I. I removed snap as well.